# Creating transparent background on skype buttons

Tags: php, html, fopen, skype

I am following this tutorial http://www.jek2k.com/wp/2008/02/08/building-a-custom-skype-me-button-with-status-icon/ to get transparent skype buttons on my website so that people can call me from a click of a button. Skype have their own however the background is white, http://www.skype.com/intl/en-us/tell-a-friend/get-a-skype-button/

my code for this is:

```
          <?php
function getSkypeStatus($username) {
    /*
    returns:
    0 - unknown
    1 - offline
    2 - online
    3 - away
    4 - not available
    5 - do not disturb
    6 - invisible
    7 - skype me
    */
    $remote_status = fopen ('http://mystatus.skype.com/'.$username.'.num', 'r');
    if (!$remote_status) {
        return '0';
        exit;
    }
    while (!feof ($remote_status)) {
        $value = fgets ($remote_status, 1024);
        return trim($value);
    }
    fclose($remote_status);
}

function getSkypeStatusIcon($username) {
    $status = getSkypeStatus($username);
    // change the path of the icons folder to match your site
    echo '<img src="/skype/'.$status.'.png" alt="call '.$username.'" />';
}

// retrieves the numeric status code
//getSkypeStatus('nicolovolpato');

// displays the status icon, change to match your Skype username
getSkypeStatusIcon('myusernamehere');
?>
```

When i go to test this out on my website it just comes up: 'call myusernamehere'. there is not image and i cannot click on call myusernamehere to open skype and call.

I have inserted the images 0-7 in a folder called skype in my root folder.

can anyone help

Comment: Apart from the fact that this `getSkypeStatus` function is everything but well-written: Try opening the source code of that webpage from your browser, to see if the HTML is correct.

Comment: have you any other solution spark?

Answer (score 0):

### 1)

The issue is related to the image path that probably is not being properly constructed, or the image it self is not present at the specified location, since the browser is presenting the `alt` attribute.

**Here where you specify the Skype image path:**

```
echo '<img src="/skype/'.$status.'.png" alt="call '.$username.'" />';
```

The output when the image can't be found is `call '.$username.'` with is the content given for the `alt` attribute.

> When i go to test this out on my website it just comes up: 'call myusernamehere'.

You can use a DOM inspector tool, e.g., Firebug, to confirm that the image path specified at the `src` attribute is being properly constructed.

### 2)

If you access the image by browser like `http://www.mysite.com/skype/1.png`, and you are able to see it, the issue is related with the `$status` that doesn't give the expected 0 to 7 value.

Comment: @zull The images links are perfectly working, I am using a direct link from my website and it is showing all the images in browser so I am not sure where the problem lies however as you suggested it is related to $status is there anyway to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

To add the click-to-call feature, use the `<a>` tag:

```
<a href="skype:{username}?call">...</a>
```

So a modified version of this script would look like this:

```
<?php
function getSkypeStatus($username) {
    $remote_status = file_get_contents('http://mystatus.skype.com/'. $username .'.num');
    return ($remote_status === false) ? '0' : trim($remote_status);
}

function showSkypeButton($username) {
    $status = getSkypeStatus($username);

    echo '<a href="skype:'. $username .'?call">';
    echo '<img src="/skype/'. $status .'.png" alt="Call '. $username .'">';
    echo '</a>';
}

showSkypeButton('whatever');
```

The problem with the image not showing up is not related to this code. Zuul's answer is giving you some good hints on that issue.